# excel interop c#: changing row color

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to change the color in Row mod 2 = 0 in a Range between B4 to F500 which it is a list of values. I want alternate the background color of entire Row.

I am executing this:

```
Range c1 = worksheet.Range["B4"];
Range c2 = (Range) worksheet.Range[F500];

Range range = worksheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
range.Value = arr;

var formatCell = (FormatCondition)range.Rows.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=MOD(ROW(),2) = 0");
formatCell.Interior.Color =  Color.FromArgb(243, 243, 243);
```

until `value = arr` the code it is working ok but when I want to change the color it is giving me this error:

[image]

THE PARAMETER IS INCORRECT

What is wrong?

could you please help me?

I don't want to make a loop because it is too slow

I am using c# and Excel 365.

Comment: This is an example of how I color a range of cells with Interop in a web service project I made: `((Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[x + 1]).Range[((Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[x + 1]).Cells[1, 1], ((Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[x + 1]).Cells[1, cols]].Interior.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbLightGoldenrodYellow;`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
Workbook wkb = GetApp().Workbooks.Open(excelLocation);
wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, outputLocation);

wkb.Close();
GetApp().Quit();
```

The problem was `ExportAsFixedFormat` which wasn't recognized as instruction. I had a conflict with the libraries and I decided to delete all.

Only to work with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

and after it I had to install Microsoft.CSSharp as requeriment of interop.

now it is working